# Standard error of difference of estimates

Tags: estimation, least-squares, standard-error

I have two (non-independent) OLS-parameter estimates each with its own standard error. I'm trying to find out what the standard error of the difference of the estimates should be. Can anyone help? Is this too general?

Comment: Are you assuming that the two estimates you have are independent of each other?

Comment: @John no, they are not independent.

Comment: If this is all the information you have then, without an estimate of their relationship, e.g. covariance, you cannot calculate this.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail? Are they parameter estimates in a single multiple regression fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are asking about the estimates of the same OLS regression. If you have only  the estimates and their standard errors then it is not possible to estimate the standard error of the difference of the estimates. Suppose you have a regression

$$y=X\beta+\varepsilon$$

Then OLS parameter estimates $\hat\beta=(X'X)^{-1}X'y$ and you can calculate $Var(\hat\beta)$, i.e. the covariance matrix of the OLS parameter estimates. Now in your case $\beta'=(\alpha,\beta_1,\beta_2)$ and you want the standard error of the $\hat\mu=\hat\beta_1-\hat\beta_2$. For that we can use the formula $Var(\gamma'X)=\gamma'Var(X)\gamma$, which in your case becomes

$$[0,1,-1]Var(\hat\beta)[0,1,-1]',$$

since $\hat\mu=[0,1,-1]\hat\beta$.

If you do not want do algebra, there is a nice trick to achieve the same thing by rewriting inital regression. Suppose your regression model is

$$y=\alpha+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2+\varepsilon$$

Rewrite it as

$$y=\alpha+(\beta_1-\beta_2)x_1+\beta_2(x_1+x_2)+\varepsilon.$$

The two models are identical. Run the regression on the second model and the standard error reported on $x_1$ will be the standard error of the difference $\hat\beta_1-\hat\beta_2$.

Here is the example in R illustrating both approaches

```
set.seed(1)
x1 = rnorm(100)
x2 = rnorm(100)
y = 1+ 2*x1 + 3*x2 + rnorm(100)
dt = data.frame(y=y,x1=x1,x2=x2)

#First approach
m1 = lm(y~x1+x2,data=dt)

#Standard error is the square root of variance
est1 = sqrt(t(c(0, 1, -1)) %*% vcov(m1) %*% t(t(c(0, 1, -1))))

m2=lm(y~x1+I(x1+x2),data=dt)
summary(m2)
est2 = coef(summary(m2))[2,2]

##Compare the estimates
est1-est2
```